# How to add a custom component in real-time?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-component

Okay, I created a custom component under the namespace `My_Namespace`. Then somewhere in the code I'm trying to add my custom component in real-time:

```
public void Some_Method()
{
  My_Namespace.My_Custom_Component my_component;

  my_component.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
  my_component.Name = "my_component";
  my_component.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(380, 380);

  this.Controls.Add(my_component);
}
```

However I get this error

> Error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'my_component'

I don't understand because `my_component` is declared at the start of my method.

Anyone know what's wrong? Otherwise how is the good way to call a custom component in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it should be instead:

```
My_Namespace.My_Custom_Component my_component = new My_Namespace.My_Custom_Component();
```

You cannot use an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

my_component is null, you should initialize it before use it.